# How to get the X-Servers complete address

Tags: ssh, sudo, xserver

Edited concerning the answer of @terdon.

**On my ubuntu computer:**

If I connect a server via `ssh -X my_server`, then I can start a program.

Then I use `sudo -i` to become root, but I can't start the same program.
Error:

> X11 connection rejected because of wrong authentication.
> qt.qpa.xcb: could not connect to display localhost:18.0
> qt.qpa.plugin: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "" even though it was found.
> This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.
>
> Available platform plugins are: eglfs, linuxfb, minimal, minimalegl, offscreen, vnc, xcb.
>
> Aborted (core dumped)

---

I have a **windows vm** with **MobaXterm**. It shows me the address the X server uses.

[image]

If I do the same as above, I have the same problem. But I can type `export DISPLAY=172.30.4.66:0.0` and it works.

`echo $DISPLAY` then gives me the entered address.

---

How can I get these address on my ubuntu comuter?

By typing `echo $DISPLAY` I get `:0`. And `export DISPLAY=<my ip>:0` doesn't work.

The "x11-xserver-utils" are not installed (there is **no xhost**).

Answer (score 0):

First, you never need `sudo su`, why use 2 programs when one will do? Just run `sudo -i`. Second, why do you need this at all? If you want to run the program as root, just run `sudo programName`. Next, this isn't about getting the IP (and, by the way, there is no point in obfuscating your IP: 172.30.4.66 is an internal address on your home network, it isn't your public IP), it is about allowing access.

If you really want root to be able to launch graphical programs on your X session, you need to run `xhost +` to allow all users access. So just run `xhost +` and then try launching. If that doesn't work, update your question with the output.

Comment: youre right in all points, I think. But ask me questions and didn't answere my one. - I'll look about `xhost +`. - Thanks so far.

Comment: The answer is the xhost command.